# RPPreviewViewController's share extension invalidated with ReplayKit

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, replaykit

After recording video using ReplayKit, the RPPreviewController is presented. But when selecting Messages from the share extension, the screen goes black.

The following is logged out at this time:

```
plugin com.apple.ReplayKit.RPVideoEditorExtension interrupted

plugin com.apple.ReplayKit.RPVideoEditorExtension invalidated

viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

Any thoughts as to why the extension is becoming "invalidated" and the Messages extension is broken?

*Update:* I submitted this bug report to Apple and was told it is a duplicate  of bug report 22750239. Not sure how I can check the progress however (Apple's bug reporting system is quite frustrating).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when the recording was stopped before it started. Try letting the record process continue a little longer and then stopping it.